Why "onClick" has this type error on Astrojs?
I get this error, whenever I try to add onClick or onclick:

Type '{ children: string; disabled: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'. Did you mean 'onclick'?ts(2322)

This is my code:
import { databases } from "../../lib/appwrite";
import Layout from "../../layouts/Layout.astro";
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar.astro";

const databaseId = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DATABASE_ID;
const collectionID = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_COLLECTION_ID;

const { documents: allNews } = await databases.listDocuments(
  databaseId,
  collectionID
);

let currentPage = 1;
const itemsPerPage = 3;
const totalPages = Math.ceil(allNews.length / itemsPerPage);

const getPaginatedNews = () => {
  const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
  return allNews.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
};

const goToPage = (page: number) => {
  currentPage = page;
};

<Layout title="News | Gaxve Music">
  <main>
    <Navbar />
    <ul
      class={`news-list ${getPaginatedNews().length >= 3 ? "justify-between" : ""}`}
    >
      {
        getPaginatedNews().map((post) => {
          return (
            <li class="news-card dark-mode">
              <img src={post.image} alt="News Image" class="news-image" />
              <div class="news-content">
                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                <p class="news-date">
                  {new Date(post.$createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                </p>
                <p class="news-excerpt">{post.excerpt}</p>
                <a href={`/news/${post.slug}`} class="read-more-button">
                  Read More
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })
      }
    </ul>
    <div class="pagination">
      <button
        disabled={currentPage === 1}
        onClick={() => goToPage(currentPage - 1)}
      >
        Previous
      </button>
      <span>{`Page ${currentPage} of ${totalPages}`}</span>
      <button
        disabled={currentPage === totalPages}
        onClick={() => goToPage(currentPage + 1)}
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  </main>

I tried using onClick and onclick also changing from button to a and nothing works

You're trying to use react style JSX in an astro template. You can't do that. Read https://docs.astro.build/en/basics/astro-syntax/#dynamic-attributes. Specifically the part which warns you and says: "use a client-side script to add the event handler, like you would in vanilla JavaScript".
